# GBM Models not showing in h2o Steam Model Category

Tags: h2o

I have a GBM model I would like to add to a project in Steam, however the model is not showing up in the list of Model options. The "Select a Model Category List" does not include an option for any type of model after I select the data frame I wish to include in the project (if the GBM is the only model on the server). If I make a GLM model on the same data frame then "Regression" is listed as an option but only the GLM model is available to select to create the project with; the GBM is still hidden. I don't see anywhere in the docs that GBM is not available for projects in Steam but is this the case? Is there a bug where GBM Regression models are not being found as options? I'm able to view the GBM model through R and Flow so it's definitely there on the server. I am running h2o version 3.10.4.6 and Steam version 1.1.16.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

GBM models are supported in Steam. Are you using Steam on YARN or using Steam on a local machine?

I just tested this locally using H2O 3.10.4.6 and Steam version 1.1.6. I created GLM and GBM regression models using the same dataframe. I then created a project and selected that dataframe. My “Select Model Category” dropdown included only the Regression option because that dataframe was used only for the two regression models. Both the GLM and GBM models were then available in the Models to Import table.

Can you verify that the dataframe you’re selecting is the one used to create that GBM model?

Comment: the data frame I used for training is definitely the one I used to build the GBM; After I didn't see it the first time I did what you did, just start an h2o server with only the training frame and the two models. I'm using Steam on a local machine, and also an AWS server and neither have been able to see the model.